# How does currying lambda expressions work?

Tags: python, lambda, currying

I have no clue how the code executes. This is a question on a practice test.

```
(lambda x: x(x))(lambda y:4)
```

The output is 4 but I don't know how the code runs. I think the steps are as follows:

1. lambda (x) is defined
2. executes lambda (x)
3. returns x(lambda(y))
4. lambda (y) is defined
5. returns 4
6. x(4)?

I know step 6 is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky question.

Lambdas are anonymous functions.  Let's define them to help you understand what is happening.

```
# (lambda x: x(x))
def func_1(func):
    return func(func)

# (lambda y: 4)
def func_2(y):
    return 4

>>> func_1(func_2)  # Equivalent to (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y:4)
4
```

The second function is just a callable that returns the constant value of 4 regardless of the value of `y`, so `func_2(10)` and `func_2(0)` both return 4.

The first function is a callable with itself as the single argument to the function (`x(x)`).  We just saw that the second function is a callable that will return the constant value 4 regardless of the input argument, so `func_2(func_2)` simply returns 4.

Comment: I guess where I’m getting stuck up on is that it doesn’t produce an error. Is it right to say func_2(func_2) produces func_2(4) which then produces 4. The comment below says the second lambda doesn’t print and that doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: The left most lambda runs first a returns a _callable_ that takes a _callable_ as its sole parameter (one knows it takes a callable because you can see that it calls itself via `x(x)`.  Try running it on its own and it will return something like `<function __main__.<lambda>(x)>`. This function is then called with the second lambda callable as the sole argument, which simply returns 4 regardless of the argument provided.

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` expression works just like an unnamed function (anonymous functions). And works like this:

```
lambda (1): (2)
```

(1) are parameters

(2) the return

See:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

Using lambda expression:

```
square = lambda x: x**2

>>> square(2)
4
```

But think about the use, maybe you just want to use an function a few times, why store it? Create an anonymous function! How? running a lambda function:

```
>>> (lambda x: x**2)(2)
4
```

See? Not that hard. Let's think together.

```
(lambda x: x(x))(lambda y:4)
```

`lambda y: 4` is passed to our `lambda x` function, now x = (lambda y: 4) (crazy thing!). x(x) are equals to (lambda y: 4)((lambda y: 4)). Look! We got an parameter to our first 'y' it is (lambda y: 4)! then the first function are executed, and returns 4. What about the second? It doesn't run, and don't need to run! if you do x(x(x)) the second function will run, but not the third one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about "lambda is defined". A lambda is a value, like `4`. You don't "define" a `4` - it just is. When evaluating a lambda, just replace its (evaluated) arguments into its body (adding parentheses where neccessary). Work it like a rewriting problem.

```
(lambda x: x(x))(lambda y:4)
# rewrite all `x` in `x(x)` to `lambda y:4` (two appearances):
(lambda y:4)(lambda y:4)
# rewrite all `y` in `4` to `lambda y:4` (zero appearances):
4
```

Comment: Does the left most lambda run first? If so does the right lambda become the input ‘x’ into the first lambda?

Comment: In python (and in many other programming languages, as well as maths where it came from) the syntax `f(x, y, z)` will evaluate the function `f` with arguments `x, y, z`. A lambda is effectively a function. Thus, in `(lambda x: x)(lambda y:y)`, `lambda x: x` is the function to be evaluated; `lambda y; y` is the argument to be passed into the function (becoming local parameter `x`). If Python were to have a weird function syntax like `(x, y, z)f`, then it would be vice versa. Does that make sense?